Evaluation of Limit using Stirling's Approximation
Find the limit
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\frac{n!}{n^n\sqrt{n}}},$$
using Stirling's Approximation
$$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{\theta_n}{4n}}, \quad \theta_n\in(0,1).$$
My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\frac{n!}{n^n\sqrt{n}}} 
&  =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)^n\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^ne^{\frac{\theta_n}{4n}}}{n^n\sqrt{n}}}\\
& =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{e^n\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}e^{\frac{\theta_n}{4n}}}{e^n}} = \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt{2\pi}e^{\frac{\theta_n}{4n}}}\\ &= \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt{2\pi}\cdot1}\\ &=\sqrt{2\pi}
\end{align*}
Is this valid? I'm especially unsure about whether the step where I replaced $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ by  $e$ is sound.

Indeed it is a wrong step, we have
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\frac{n!}{n^n\sqrt{n}} \approx \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}{n^n\sqrt{n}} =\sqrt{2\pi }\;\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}{e^n}$$
with
$$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}{e^n}=e^{n^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-n} =e^{-\frac12+O(1/n)} \to \frac1{\sqrt e}$$
using that $\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+O(x^3)$ as $x\to 0$.
